# Preventing CSRF while using CORS?

Tags: security, cross-domain, csrf

I am making a bookmarklet so that a user can cross domain post to my server using CORS from any page. The user has to authenticate before posting and cookies are used. Is there any way to prevent a malicious website from imbedding javascript code in their webpage to do cross domain post to my server using the user's credential?

Comment: No. Maybe you could consider posting to an `iframe` under your website's control instead, and then have users `confirm()` before posting. Or you could embed an unique CSRF token into each user's bookmarklet, and then... Wait, I'm getting an idea...

Answer (score 1):

In theory, there may be a solution for this.

1. Embed a unique CSRF token in each user's bookmarklet.
2. Wrap the code in the bookmarklet in an anonymous function, so the page won't have access to it.
3. Embed [a strong hash function](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2) in your bookmarklet. This has to be placed entirely within the bookmarklet's code, to ensure it can't be tampered with.
4. In your XMLHttpRequest, you send:

   1. The message
   2. The hash of:

      1. The message
      2. Your CSRF token
      3. A unique, long salt
      4. A UserID
      5. A timestamp (just to make sure the message was sent now and not at another time)
   3. The salt
   4. The timestamp
   5. A userID
5. At your server, you validate:

   1. That the timestamp is within the allowed error margin (which is necessary because a user's computer clock may be off)
   2. That the hash is correct
6. If everything is correct, you can post the message.

There is one flaw with this concept: if a website tampers with any of the functions used by the bookmarklet (such as `Array()`), the malicious website may still be able to intercept, copy and / or modify the message, userID or CSRF token.